# To open and to be opened

Tags: word-usage

I read this sentence in CNNMoney.

"The Chinese firm expects to hire 400 American workers to run the refurbished factory, slated to **open** in late 2017."

If I rewrite the sentence to
"The Chinese firm expects to hire 400 American workers to run the refurbished factory, slated to **be opened** in late 2017.

Do both the sentences mean the same ?

Comment: I would say that the two sentences – your version, and the original – mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the meaning the same.  The only difference is the use of the passive voice, which changes the verb "open" from the *intransitive* to the *transitive*.  A more straightforward example:

> The door opens (intransitive)
>
> I open the door (transitive)
>
> The door is opened by me (transitive passive)

The only change in nuance is that, with a transitive verb, there must be a subject, someone doing the action.  In my example there would be a difference between "the door opens" and "the door is opened" -- the first implies that the door possibly opened "by itself", while the second directly states the *actor* doing the *action*.

However, in your question, since *stores* don't open by themselves, the team responsible for opening it is implied.  We know the store didn't open on its own.

This raises the question why the author wrote the sentence this way.  By removing the subject from the action, the writer retains the focus on the *store* as the subject of the sentence, rather than the people responsible for opening it.  Related example:

> The race will start in ten minutes.

I could have said "we will start the race in ten minutes" but with the intransitive I retain focus on the important stuff -- the race -- without the unnecessary distraction of the people who will actually start it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your answer.  Just a question on the example given by you :"The race will start in ten minutes". I can understand that you keep the sentence in intransitive form to retain focus on the race, but is the sentence grammatically correct ? Do you think  "The race will be started in ten minutes" is a better way of writing the sentence without losing the focus on the important stuff-the race and yet grammatically correct ?. Thanks

Comment: It's fine to say "the race will be started ..." but this is a good example of when English speakers choose the intransitive verb over the transitive passive verb.  In many languages the passive voice has additional nuance because it allows you to avoid naming a subject, and possibly causing embarrassment, e.g. "mistakes were made".  So if you choose to talk about the race this way it sounds a little weird and invites additional questions.

Answer (score -1):

There is a subtle difference between the two sentences, with the first being correct *in this case*. One would use the second sentence in connection with a place (like a plaza, shopping centre or even hospital) where people *go into* the place: it is open (as opposed to closed).

It seems that the passive version would have been the original use of the verb, whose meaning changed over the years to the active version. A firm cannot literally 'open' as it has no entrance (although a factory could); it is not a physical or even mental structure. But a firm can figuratively 'open', as in 'open for business'.

"To be opened" also implies that there will be an opening ceremony in which (for example) a shopping centre is officially opened and when someone cuts the blue ribbon. This doesn't happen with a company, although it could happen to a *building* belonging to the company (for example, 'the south campus of the university').